# Redundant use of generators? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, generator

say we did the following: (ignore if this is silly or if there is a better way, it's a simplified example)

```
from itertools import izip

def check(someList):
    for item in someList:
        yield item[0]

for items in izip(check(someHugeList1), check(someHugeList2)):
    //some logic
```

since check is a generator, is it redundant to use izip? Would using regular zip be just as good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular `zip()` would expand the whole generator first. You wouldn't want to do that with a huge or endless generator.

Demo:

```
>>> def gen():
...     print 'generating'
...     yield 'a'
... 
>>> gen()
<generator object gen at 0x10747f320>
>>> zip(gen(), gen())
generating
generating
[('a', 'a')]
```

Note that directly creating the generator doesn't print anything; the generator is still in the paused state. But passing the generator to `zip()` immediately produces output, which can only be produced by iterating over the generators in full.

Comment: Ah, so its just like doing say, `list(), or tuple()`

Answer (score 1):

On Python 3, zip behaves same as Python2's izip. On Python2, izip returns a generator while zip returns a list, izip would be better in memory(doesn't create a new list.).

Comment: I meant builtin zip behaves same as Python2's izip. Fixed the wording, thanks.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: The second sentence is directly relevant. And should you move on to Python 3 (which is a much better language than Python 2), the first one is as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Without meaning to start a dispute, simply hearing over and over that people should move to Python3 is just not cutting it anymore. Many people can't simply move to 3 and for many 3 is a failure. 

http://www.robg3d.com/?p=1175
http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/5/unicode-in-2-and-3/
http://alexgaynor.net/2013/dec/30/about-python-3/

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: Thank you for these interesting links! I still think that Py3k is *much* better, but I also see how the transition is difficult for many.